# why the tf.nn.dynamic_rnn returns different result regarding sequence_length

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

while i studied RNN in the book called Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow, i encountered different result which must be the same.

---

## first code

```
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5

reset_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)

seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

X_batch = np.array([
        # step 0     step 1
        [[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]], # instance 1
        [[3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0]], # instance 2 (padded with zero vectors)
        [[6, 7, 8], [6, 5, 4]], # instance 3
        [[9, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1]], # instance 4
    ])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    outputs_val, states_val = sess.run(
        [outputs, states], feed_dict={X: X_batch})
```

## result

```
[[[ 0.10273618  0.03536123  0.14367972  0.1572928   0.23754682]
  [ 0.41665766  0.49650002  0.1549654   0.07568012  0.82703578]]

 [[ 0.35701871  0.20796996  0.13533755  0.21938165  0.64902753]
  [ 0.15402019  0.14915846  0.31022152  0.13305351  0.36220491]]

 [[ 0.48224443  0.24930702  0.07341093  0.18052572  0.72496963]
  [ 0.3561081   0.55856758  0.31825539  0.13380432  0.90042865]]

 [[ 0.02311822 -0.16510175  0.49798414 -0.06049323  0.23668778]
  [ 0.28713134  0.16252561  0.4774358   0.07630309  0.50222367]]]
```

---

## second code

```
    n_steps = 2
    n_inputs = 3
    n_neurons = 5

    reset_graph()
    
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
    basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)
    
    seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=seq_length)
    
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    
    X_batch = np.array([
            # step 0     step 1
            [[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]], # instance 1
            [[3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0]], # instance 2 (padded with zero vectors)
            [[6, 7, 8], [6, 5, 4]], # instance 3
            [[9, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1]], # instance 4
        ])
    seq_length_batch = np.array([2, 1, 2, 2])


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init.run()
        outputs_val, states_val = sess.run(
            [outputs, states], feed_dict={X: X_batch,seq_length:seq_length_batch})
```

## result

```
    [[[-0.05313011 -0.03707792 -0.00771733  0.25379574  0.06289639]
      [ 0.34355608 -0.00646485 -0.00426668  0.35139424  0.02420545]]
    
     [[ 0.07838845 -0.04377012 -0.00758527  0.44615552  0.01038414]
      [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
    
     [[ 0.16005152 -0.01226684 -0.0048396   0.48419252  0.00086438]
      [ 0.4990865  -0.03458051  0.01733598  0.35500884  0.02000519]]
    
     [[ 0.73743606 -0.00149451 -0.102979   -0.39292669  0.50247419]
      [ 0.6204772  -0.04163819 -0.4165332  -0.14101879  0.34553975]]]
```

---

Tensorflow document says 'If sequence_length not provided, all batch entries are assumed to be full sequences; and time reversal is applied from time 0 to max_time for each sequence. '

So must the result be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using random initialization of the graph parameters, hence the variance of the outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But every time I run the two code I get the same result. And I didn't set any initializer.

Comment: interesting, i couldn't reproduce your results. Also, each `lstm` cell as own parameters which are initialized by `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()`. without initialization you cant run the ops.